# How do I store Wine related program files in Ubuntu's partitions?

Tags: wine

Hi guys I loved Linux operating systems and trying out new now.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. I am using Wine & Playonlinux to run windows programs. I an having a little problem. Whenever I save a edited file its shows option to save in "virtual drive".

How can I access the files from Ubuntu desktop? Is there anyway I can save my files directly to the local partitions of my system?

Answer (score 1):

It should be accessible on drive Z:\ I think, or something similar.

Programs running in wine can definitely access the ubuntu file system.

Answer (score 1):

The `c:` drive of wine is stored at `/home/your_user_name/.wine/dosdevices/c:` (obs: `/home/your_user_name/.wine/drive_c` points to the same place if you prefer).

If using `z:` drive in wine programs, you will save to your home directory (`/home/your_user`)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you run Configure Wine, you can create custom drive locations under the 'drives' tab, though it's generally easy enough to just use z:

p.s. How do I add comments to existing answers? It sometimes gives me the option and other times doesn't, don't know why.